# requestLocationUpdates with Criteria doesn't work

Tags: android, location

Here's the code:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
manager.requestLocationUpdates(0,0, criteria, locationListener, null); // doesn't work
```

The Listener never gets an update if i pass criteria as argument. However, if i get provider from cirteria and pass to different arguments of request locationUpdates, it works

```
manager.requestLocationUpdates(manager.getBestProvider(criteria, true), 0, 0, locationListener); // works
```

Is the [manager.requestLocationUpdates(0,0, criteria, listener, looper)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper)) method broken in the API?

Comment: Instead of LoactionManger have to Check out this : https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: @HareshChhelana I know of that. I'm asking if this API is broken so that I should report it. I tried on several phones and it didnt work.